# Combining duplicate rows in excel without loosing the order or sequence

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have data that looks like this

```
-Name       Duration
-Session 1  00:00:30
-Session 1  00:01:30
-Session 1  01:00:30
-Session 2  00:00:30
-Session 2  00:00:30
-Session 2  01:00:30
-Session 1  00:00:45
-Session 1  00:01:30
-Session 1  01:00:45
-Session 2  00:00:20
-Session 2  00:00:20
-Session 2  01:00:20
```

I want to output to be like below after consolidation i.e. addition of duration

```
-Name        Duration
-Session 1   01:02:30
-Session 2   01:01:30
-Session 1   01:03:00
-Session 2   01:01:00
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: I have used excel formula to combine the vertical cell values and mark the beginning and ending in a different row ,but that is giving unreliable results. Something like this to mark a session and it's end in a separate column =IF(G2=G3,"SESSION",IF(G2=G1,"END","SINGLE SESSION"))

Comment: My thought was if i can mark the beginning and end of each session based on vertical comparison of cells , then I can write a macro to calculate the durations based on the flags.

Comment: Try the Answer below. It is a Macro Solution, just make sure to put in the Correct Range for it to Work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Macro will give you the same Answer:

Change the Range as per the Screenshot.

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim val As Double: val = 0

For Each cel In ActiveSheet.Range("K5:K16") 'Change the Range to which cells Contains Session Text , Not the Time

    If cel.Value = cel.Offset(1, 0).Value Then

        val = val + cel.Offset(0, 1).Value

    Else

        MsgBox cel.Value & " - " & Format(val + cel.Offset(0, 1).Value, "hh:mm:ss")
        val = 0

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mikku , Let me try and confirm , appreciate your response

Comment: Sure @rk_manne ... Also you can replace the MsgBox line with Range to put the Value on any cell in your sheet. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Index column + `Power Query` *(a free add-in from MS in Excel versions since 2010)*, included in 2016+ known as `Get&Transform`.

- Add an Index column to your original table

---

```
  =IF(A2=A1,N(C1),N(C1)+1)
```

Then, in the Power Query Editor

- Change the Data Type of the Duration column to `Duration`
- Group by the `Index` column and the `-Name` column in that order

  - Choose `Sum` as the type of aggregation, and give the new column a name (eg `Total Duration`

[image]

- Delete the `Index` Column.
- `Close and Load`  or `Load To`

**Source and Results**

[image]

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"-Name", type text}, {"Duration", type duration}, {"Index", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Index", "-Name"}, {{"Total Duration", each List.Sum([Duration]), type duration}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

***Note:***  *It is possible to set up the Index column within Power Query, but much simpler to do it on the Excel worksheet.*

Comment: looks like a unique solution , let me try and confirm, appreciate your response

Answer (score 0):

Using Excel formulas, it would be

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(A$2:A$13<>A$1:A$12,ROW(A$2:A$13)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

to get the session

and

```
=IFERROR(SUM(INDEX(B:B,SMALL(IF(A$2:A$13<>A$1:A$12,ROW(A$2:A$13)),ROW(1:1))):
INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(A$2:A$13<>A$3:A$14,ROW(A$2:A$13)),ROW(1:1)))),"")
```

to get the sum within the session.

Both formulas must be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tom Sharpe , Let me try and confirm , appreciate your response